# Menu Options with User-Generated Content

Tags: javascript, html, json, user-interface, user-generated-content

I'd like to create a menu with options that users input. User inputs will most likely be stored in a JSON object.

One way to go about it would be jstree. But are there any good alternatives out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on what you are doing with it and how you are dealing with it, but basic javascript objects is plenty to implement this.

```js
    menu = {}
    menu["apple"] = 1.99
    menu["bagle"] = {price: 3.50, by:"KawaiUser99"}
    console.log(Object.keys(menu))
    document.write(JSON.stringify(menu))
```